# How to delete a line of code from a commit that is pushed into the github?

Tags: github

So it happened that I accidentally added an empty line of code and I need to remove it, but how to do it, how to kill it?

Comment: The easiest way it to make another commit with the change. If you have to erase your mistake from history it can be done, but it's not recommended, especially for beginners

Comment: The problem is that I did it, this is my job and it was not accepted, I was told to kill it, I would like to use it to live revert

Comment: The title originally said "poured", which I assume meant "pushed". Have you pushed or are the changes still local?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using an interpreter. I created a new branch in the project, filled in the changes in it and now I need to remove from it an empty line that accidentally ended up in the commit.

Comment: How big is the commit? If you delete it, you will delete all the other changes too, and have to do them again.

Answer (score 0):

1. delete that line from your local master branch.
2. Push it to origin master after you commit it.
3. ta da.

Comment: I need to have it not at all in the history of changes, your method creates another commit where I delete it, I was forbidden to do so.

Comment: So if your repo on origin is bare, nothing could be done as a log would show your commit. If it’s non bare like github or bitbucket, ask your team lead or whoever has the rights, to just delete that commit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [this article](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html) to see how to do it, and why you shouldn't.

In short

1. Make a new commit is easier
2. Reverting the commit as a new commit is not that hard either
3. You can do it, but you'd better get it right, and other developers won't like you

As an aside, this sounds like a bad place to work if this has caused an issue. Git is meant to show you this history of what everyone has done. Re-writing it defeats the point.